# Align control to bottom of panel in wxPython

Tags: python-2.7, wxpython

I'm trying to align some controls in my wxPython app to bottom of a panel. Here's sample of my code:

```
def __DoLayout(self):
    vsizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    hsizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    hsizer2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

    hsizer.Add(self.prog, 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
    hsizer2.Add(self.text, 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)

    #hsizer.Add(self.timer, 0, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALIGN_RIGHT)

    vsizer.Add(hsizer2, 0, wx.EXPAND)
    vsizer.Add(hsizer, 0, wx.ALIGN_BOTTOM|wx.EXPAND)

    self.SetSizer(vsizer)
```

I would like the bottom horizontal sizer (hsizer) to stretch to bottom, or the top one to stretch placing bottom sizer on the bottom (that would actually be better).

[EDIT: Proposed sulution description]

> The proportion parameter defines the ratio of how will the widgets change in the defined orientation. Let's assume we have three buttons with the proportions 0, 1, and 2. They are added into a horizontal wx.BoxSizer. Button with proportion 0 will not change at all. Button with proportion 2 will change twice more than the one with proportion 1 in the horizontal dimension.

[From zetcode](http://zetcode.com/wxpython/layout/)
Solution proposed by [Renae Lider](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4181692/renae-lider)

Comment: Change the `0` to `1` in this line : `vsizer.Add(hsizer2, 1, wx.EXPAND)`

Comment: Thanks :D works like a charm ;)

Comment: You should explain that what you are changing is the `proportion` flag, so that others get the gist of this answer. proportion (int) –  it is used in BoxSizer to indicate if a child of a sizer can change its size in the main orientation of the BoxSizer - where 0 stands for not changeable and a value of more than zero is interpreted relative to the value of other children of the same BoxSizer.

Comment: I can edit question and add your comment if you like

Comment: @Piotr. Sorry I should have labelled my comment properly. My point was to Renae who provided the solution but who was rather parse with their explanation.

Comment: @RolfofSaxony I added description for a solution, when Renea will find some time to answer, I will mark it as answer ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With reluctance, but as @renae-lider who answered the question has not posted an answer.

Change the 0 to 1 in this line :

```
vsizer.Add(hsizer2, 1, wx.EXPAND)
```

This is the `proportion` parameter.

The proportion parameter defines the ratio of how will the widgets change in the defined orientation.

Let's assume we have three buttons with the proportions 0, 1, and 2. They are added into a horizontal wx.BoxSizer. Button with proportion 0 will not change at all. Button with proportion 2 will change twice more than the one with proportion 1 in the horizontal dimension.